# Getting error after doing runtime upgrade to substrate v1.0.0

Tags: runtime-upgrade, substrate-node, blockchain

I am trying to do runtime upgrade of substrate blockchain which is running on 0.9.36 version to substrate version v1.0.0 . While doing runtime upgrade chain stops working and getting this error in logs.

```sh
ERROR {" Error at calling runtime api: Execution failed: Execution aborted due to trap: wasm trap: wasm unreachable instruction executed"}
```

Can anyone please tell how to avoid this error without affecting blockchain.

---

I have  done this till now.
I have upgraded  versions from 0.9.36 ->0.9.37 ->...-> 0.9.43. everything is going  fine there,But when i tried to  runtime upgrade from 0.9.43 -> 1.0.0 the blockchain  stopped working and i have started receiving errors(same as above) in logs. can you please tell me what is going wrong from 0.9.43 to 1.0.0 and  provide me with some solution .

Comment: What runtime is it? The migrations need to be applied one by one and cannot be skipped.

Comment: As Oliver stated, recommended path is `0.9.36` -> `0.9.37` -> ... `1.0.0` making sure that for each upgrade the migrations are run. You can use `try-runtime` to ensure the migrations run smoothly before applying them in production.

Comment: @Bruno i am facing this  issue  only in contracts pallet .I am able to do runtime upgrade to v1.0.0 while commenting contracts pallet in runtime in 1.0.0 version .

Comment: I would do contracts pallet one polkadot version at a time. There are several migrations and there was also a multi-block migration that I believe changed the pre-existing migrations but I'd imagine it did not interfere with the actual migrations. If you do not want to do the contracts migration one release at a time then you have to see all the migrations that need to be applied from `.36` to `1.0.0` and make sure they are being applied.

Comment: @Bruno i have upgraded  versions from 0.9.36 ->0.9.37 ->...-> 0.9.43. everything is going  fine there,But when i tried to  runtime upgrade from 0.9.43 -> 1.0.0 the blockchain  stopped working and i have started receiving errors in logs.

Comment: So `0.9.43` was working fine for you? Without more details it is hard to debug your issue. We just upgraded the Trappist parachain to `1.0.0` from `0.9.43` perhaps you can look here: https://github.com/paritytech/trappist/pull/262 and compare with your parachain