# How to solve Failed to get runtime version issue?

Tags: parachain, migration, block-production, storage-migration, on-runtime-upgrade

I recently upgraded the chain from version 0.9.36 to 1.0.0. Following this update, when attempting to perform a runtime upgrade on the blockchain, I encountered an error that resulted in the chain no longer producing blocks. The error message is as follows:

```
2023-09-27 09:37:13 Proposing failed: Import failed: Error at calling runtime api: Failed to get runtime version: runtime requires function imports which are not present on the host: 'env:ext_statement_store_submit_statement_version_1
```

[image]

Comment: Your runtime upgraded caused a migration which took longer than allowed, there are some various ways of unbricking your block chain. Nodle parachain was stuck for several weeks until governance on polkadot allowed for a force upgrade

Comment: you can refer to comments in this question https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/9677/getting-error-after-doing-runtime-upgrade-to-substrate-v1-0-0

Comment: can you please explore which comment you are pointing to related migration, contract pallet or anyone else?